# changing the background-size value from contain to cover using data-attribute and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background-size from contain to cover when the screen resolution increases above 1900 ( TV Resolution size).Though I couldnot find the solution for it. We have did upto like passing the value but cannot find the answer for it . My idea is to have data-bgfit="contain" and to switch it using javascript and change the background-size from contain to cover when screen resolution changes .

Comment: this is what css media queries are for, no need for javascript

Comment: Hello. I know that media queries are for those but you cant change the background-size according to the screen size as we are having it declared inside an image

Comment: What do you mean by screen resolution? The size of the browser window or the size of the monitor.

Comment: what does `declared in an image` mean? Please provide full details of your issue

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to set the property depending on browser window size like this:

```
.element {
  background-size: contain;
}

@media (min-width: 1900px) {
  .element {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

You will need to replace the `.element` css class with whatever your HTML element uses, but that is it. No need for JavaScript.

If you want to change the property based on the computer monitor's resolution, you can find those values in a special JavaScript object `window.screen`. The thing is, there is no notification or event that you can listen for to determine when the user changes the monitor resolution. You can write a script to poll the screen resolution every so often, but it is a bad enough idea that I won't bother to show you how unless you specifically ask me.

Comment: I am so sorry that I am not clear until now . Mostly they advice me to have 2 images to switch over according to the screen size using media-query but I dont want to practise it . Rather than that we can make use of the background-size : cover and contain which delivers the same effect. If you guys could help me with this then it would be great . I will add my codings as a for your reference.

Comment: I am pretty confused about what you want to do? That said, if you are viewing the webpage on a TV screen, I assume that the browser fills the entire tv screen, so media queries should works fine.

Comment: If the browser is not full screen, why would the screen resolution matter?

Comment: check this out http://eservsolutions.com . check it in normal screen and check it in television screen.(NOTE THE SLIDER IMAGES). to check screen resolution size you can use "quirktools" Rather than setting the background-size from contain to cover the image automatically resize to the television screen size. How to achieve such kind of thing without using the media queries. If we use media query and in future if screen size changes again we have to look out for some other technique.

Comment: Can you explain the television screen setup more? Is it a PC, Apple TV, Wii, Xbox?